# How to set Exoplayer as a service

Tags: android, service

I am trying to make a music player with exoplayer but i am not able to set it as a service

```
class PlayerService : Service() {

    var exoPlayer : ExoPlayer? = null
    
    override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder? {

        setMedia()
        return MusicBinder()
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build()
        Log.d("tag","service Started")
    }
    
    inner class MusicBinder() : Binder(){
        fun getExoPLayer() = exoPlayer
    }

    private fun setMedia() {
        val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(getString(R.string.media))
        player?.prepare()
        player?.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
        player?.prepare()
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you specifically need ExoPlayer instead of something that works without trouble?

Answer (score 2):

You can and prepare exoplayer on onStartCommand override function like this

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
          exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build()
          setMedia()
          return START_STICKY;
}
```

This works for me